# Using provider directly from context vs returning it from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm noticing something new I haven't seen before.  It is possible that this isn't specific to this react component.

I tried creating a react context

```js
const MyContext = createContext({...});
```

Then, I wrote a function to return the provider

```js
const MyProvider = () => {
  return <MyContext.Provider value={...} />;
};
```

`<MyProvider />` is a function type React component and `<MyContext.Provider />` is an object type React component

When `<MyProvider />` is used to wrap components, the React app crashes.  However, directly using `<MyContext.Provider />` works like I expected.

Since those two aren't the same, is it possible to create a provider component externally and import it elsewhere to use it?

Comment: myProvider is a functional react component, it should be start with capital letter. As per react component naming convention.

Comment: @Jaisa Ram, right, that is how I had named it originally.  I apparently didn't transfer that naming scheme over when I renamed it.  Updated the post.

Comment: Instead of naming myProvider, rename it to MyProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const MyProvider = (props) => { return ( <MyContext.Provider value={...} /> { props.children } </MyProvider> ); };
```

We can import it like :

```
import { MyProvider } from '../path'
```

use

```
<MyProvider><YouComponent/></MyProvider>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are contributing to the issue I've addressed.  Can you clarify that part for me?

Comment: It turned out that the problem was that I didn't have `props.children` for a component "that doesn't know their children ahead of time".  So this answer did solve that problem.  My question originally was about a functional difference between the two components however.  I am still curious about that, but I think that it is very likely that there isn't a difference.

Comment: Your original question was, is it possible to create a provider component externally and import it elsewhere to use it?  This is an example to create.